# Problem arising from successive integrations of a piecewise function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics

I would like to understand why Mathematica produces the following output with very large numbers and how to avoid it. I suspect it has to do with how Mathematica handles precision.

I define

```
ga1[t_] =
  Piecewise[
    {{0, t < 0},
     {Sin[2 Pi t/(4*0.12)], t <= 0.12},
     {Sin[Pi/2. + 2.0 Pi (t - .12)/(4.*0.3)], t <= .42},
     {0, t <= .58},
     {-Sin[2 Pi (t - .58)/(4*0.12)], t <= 0.70},
     {-Sin[Pi/2. + 2.0 Pi (t - .7)/(4.*0.3)], t <= 1}},
    0];

ga[t_] = 
  Piecewise[{{ga1[t], t < 1}, {-ga1[t - 1], t >= 1}, {0, t >= 2}}, 0];
```

Although it may look nasty, it is quite simple

[image: Plot[ga[t],{t,0,2}]

Then I need its integral

```
qt[t_] = 
  Module[{s}, 
    FullSimplify[Integrate[ga[s], {s, 0, t}, Assumptions -> t ∈ Reals]]]
```

> ```
> \[Piecewise]  0.190986 +0.190986 Cos[2.0944 -5.23599 t]   0.7<t<=1.
> -0.190986-0.190986 Cos[7.33038 -5.23599 t]  1.7<t<=2.
> 0.0763944 (-1.+Cos[13.09 -13.09 t]) 1.<t<=1.12
> -0.26738    1.42<t<=1.58
> -0.0763944+0.190986 Cos[4.29351 -5.23599 t] 1.12<t<=1.42
> -0.190986-0.0763944 Cos[20.6822 -13.09 t]   1.58<t<=1.7
> 0.26738 0.42<t<=0.58
> 0.0763944 -0.190986 Cos[0.942478 +5.23599 t]    0.12<t<=0.42
> 0.190986 +0.0763944 Cos[7.59218 -13.09 t]   0.58<t<=0.7
> 0.152789 Sin[6.54498 t]^2   0.<t<=0.12
> 0.  True
> ```

Which again looks fine, as does its square.

```
Plot[qt[t]^2, {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image: plot]

However, the integral of its square then contains very large numbers,

```
f[t_] = Module[{s}, FullSimplify[Integrate[qt[s]^2, {s, 0, t}, 
Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals]]]
```

> ```
> \[Piecewise]  0.  t>2.||t<=0
> 0.0582234   t==1.58
> -0.0170727+0.0714922 t  0.42<t<=0.58
> 8.04759*10^44+2.02595*10^46 t   1.42<t<1.58
> -1.54413*10^45-2.02595*10^46 t-2.63796*10^43 Sin[41.3643 -26.1799 t]    1.58<t<=1.7
> 0.00154447 +0.0393937 t-0.000111461 Sin[15.1844 -26.1799 t]-0.00222923 Sin[7.59218 -13.09 t]    0.58<t<=0.7
> (-0.234137+0.629205 t+(-0.0104414+0.0273567 t) Cos[8.37758 -20.944 t]+(-0.0835312+0.218854 t) Cos[6.28319 -15.708 t]+(-0.292359+0.765988 t) Cos[4.18879 -10.472 t]-0.584718 Cos[2.0944 -5.23599 t]+1.53198 t Cos[2.0944 -5.23599 t]-0.0492421 Sec[1.0472 -2.61799 t]^4+(0.123105 t+(-0.016414+0.0410351 t) Cos[4.18879 -10.472 t]+(-0.0656561+0.16414 t) Cos[2.0944 -5.23599 t]) Sec[1.0472 -2.61799 t]^4-0.000435396 Sin[12.5664 -31.4159 t]-0.00696633 Sin[10.472 -26.1799 t]-0.0400564 Sin[8.37758 -20.944 t]-0.118428 Sin[6.28319 -15.708 t]-0.197234 Sin[4.18879 -10.472 t]-0.167192 Sin[2.0944 -5.23599 t])/(3. +Cos[4.18879 -10.472 t]+4. Cos[2.0944 -5.23599 t])^2  0.7<t<=1.
> -3.87872*10^45+9.49666*10^45 t+3.16555*10^45 Sin[4.29351 -5.23599 t]    1.12<t<=1.42
> (-7.8126*10^47+2.22224*10^47 t+(-4.44448*10^46+8.88896*10^45 t) Cos[29.3215 -20.944 t]+(-3.55558*10^47+7.11117*10^46 t) Cos[21.9911 -15.708 t]+2.84447*10^47 Cos[14.6608 -10.472 t]+2.84447*10^47 t Cos[14.6608 -10.472 t]+3.62669*10^48 Cos[7.33038 -5.23599 t]+6.40005*10^47 t Cos[7.33038 -5.23599 t]+(7.11117*10^46 t+(-3.55558*10^46+1.77779*10^46 t) Cos[14.6608 -10.472 t]+(-1.42223*10^47+7.11117*10^46 t) Cos[7.33038 -5.23599 t]) Sec[3.66519 -2.61799 t]^4-2.7778*10^44 Sin[43.9823 -31.4159 t]-5.5556*10^45 Sin[36.6519 -26.1799 t]-1.77779*10^46 Sin[29.3215 -20.944 t]-2.7778*10^46 Sin[21.9911 -15.708 t]-1.60279*10^47 Sin[14.6608 -10.472 t]-1.15556*10^47 Sin[7.33038 -5.23599 t]-4.44448*10^45 Sin[7.33038 -5.23599 t])/(3. +Cos[14.6608 -10.472 t]+4. Cos[7.33038 -5.23599 t])^2    1.7<t<=2.
> -9.16584*10^44+3.79867*10^45 t+3.16555*10^44 Sin[13.09 (-1.+t)]-1.97847*10^43 Sin[26.1799 (-1.+t)]  1.<t<=1.12
> 0.00875415 t-0.00089169 Sin[13.09 t]+0.000111461 Sin[26.1799 t] 0.<t<=0.12
> 0.002843 +0.0240739 t-0.00557307 Sin[0.942478 +5.23599 t]+0.00174158 Sin[1.88496 +10.472 t] True
> ```

and the plot is

[image: Plot of f]

whereas the plot from using `NIntegrate` is more reasonable

```
fn[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[qt[s]^2, {s, 0, t}];
Plot[fn[t], {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Numerical Integration]

I guess I could work around by defining variables for all numbers until the end, but it seems a bit superfluous for my purposes.

Comment: The function you define is not the function you plotted. Is this intentional?

Comment: Try flattening the nested piecewise definitions by defining `ga[t_] = PiecewiseExpand[
  Piecewise[{{ga1[t], t < 1}, {-ga1[t - 1], t >= 1}, {0, t >= 2}}, 0]]`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks: I did try flattening after posting, but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: It seems to do it for me, I get the same plot for `f` as yours for `fn`.

Comment: @yohbs : which plot are you thinking about? The plots are of ga[t], qt[t]^2, f[t] and fn[t].

Comment: @b.gatessucks, that is odd - just tried it again with a fresh kernel. I am using Mathematica 11.

Comment: Btw, the whole thing takes about a minute to execute, although it is very elementary functions. Thought it ought to be a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
ga1[t_] = Piecewise[{{0, t < 0}, {Sin[2 Pi t/(4*0.12)], 
 t <= 0.12}, {Sin[Pi/2. + 2.0 Pi (t - .12)/(4.*0.3)], 
 t <= .42}, {0, t <= .58}, {-Sin[2 Pi (t - .58)/(4*0.12)], 
 t <= 0.70}, {-Sin[Pi/2. + 2.0 Pi (t - .7)/(4.*0.3)], t <= 1}}, 0];

ga[t_] = PiecewiseExpand[
  Piecewise[{{ga1[t], t < 1}, {-ga1[t - 1], t >= 1}, {0, t >= 2}}, 0]];
qt[t_] = Integrate[ga[s], {s, 0, t}, Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals];
f[t_] = Integrate[qt[s]^2, {s, 0, t}, Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals];

Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Also tried adding PiecewiseExpand around qt[s]^2 in the last integration to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem if all numbers are exact, e.g.

```
ga1[t_] = Piecewise[{{0, t < 0}, {Sin[2 Pi t/(4*12/100)], 
 t <= 12/100}, {Sin[Pi/2 + 2 Pi (t - 12/100)/(4*3/10)], 
 t <= 42/100}, {0, t <= 58/100}, {-Sin[2 Pi (t - 58/100)/(4*12/100)], 
 t <= 7/10}, {-Sin[Pi/2 + 2 Pi (t - 7/10)/(4*3/10)], t <= 1}}, 0];

ga[t_] = PiecewiseExpand[Piecewise[{{ga1[t], t < 1}, {-ga1[t - 1],
t >=1}, {0, t >= 2}}, 0]];

qt[t_] = Module[{s}, FullSimplify[Integrate[ga[s], {s, 0, t}, 
Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals]]]

f[t_] = Module[{s}, FullSimplify[Integrate[PiecewiseExpand[qt[s]^2], {s, 0, t}, 
 Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals]]]

Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Not sure I fully understand why. In the exact result no numbers ever come near close to as big as in my original post.